# Dynamic Array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I'm having problems getting dynamic arrays to work in my project. I've tried just making a small test code to get it working on its own. Here is what I have tested:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;

    int* myarray = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        myarray[i] = i + 1;
    }

    delete[] myarray;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect this code to return to me an array filled with 1,2,3,...,n until size but instead it only allocates a single index in memory. I'm really unsure where I am going wrong with this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: use std::vector<int>

Comment: Your code seems to be working to me... try printing out with `cout << myarray[i] << endl;` the line after the assignment, inside the for loop, and you can see the array contents.

Comment: your code is working fine..

Comment: The cout showed me that it works fine but then another question is why does it not show me the contents when I look at the local variables in the debug?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code works just fine, there's no technical problem.

Comment: @EmpireDuckie Because the debugger isn't smart enough to know there's more than one element.

Comment: If you are using visual studio (and perhaps others) in your watch window put
myarray,100
and it will show you the first 100 elements in the array

Comment: Awesome! it worked thank you very much guys

Answer (score -1):

You need to use C++ vectors. Vectors are basically dynamic arrays.

Comment: The code is OK like this. Why using - in this case - vectors?